# Opportunity record on creation defaults to deleted stage value

Tags: opportunity, picklist

I deactivated couple of stages from the Stage field on my Opportunity object and replaced them with new ones.

However when I create an opportunity record, the Stage picklist defaults to an old stage value which was deactivated. To test further, I deleted that value from the Stage picklist but it still shows up in the Stage picklist and the record on creation defaults to it.

I checked and there are no triggers which would set the stage on record insertion so its definitely not Apex issue.

Here is the active picklist for Stage:
[image]

But when I create an opportunity record, it defaults to a stage named: Découverte (which has been deleted from the picklist).

[image]

Any idea what might be going on. I am working on a partial copy sandbox.

Comment: Are you creating the Opportunity via a Quick Action or the New button on its record page?

Comment: New button on the Opportunities list page

Comment: A shot in the dark: have you tried emptying your trashbin? It might be that your deleted stage still exists there

Comment: How about Workflow Rules or Processes on the object?

Comment: Do you use [Sales Processes](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/admin_intro_opptys_leads/admin_intro_opptys_leads_opportunities)? I'd guess that somehow the value is default there.

Comment: So I emptied the Recycle Bin (for all) and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Any record in Salesforce can still be referenced as long as it is not fully removed. Deleting a record moves it to the trashbin where it resides until it is automatically removed or by clearing the Recycle Bin.

Only the final deletion of a record (and this includes setup records as well) will ensure that no references keep existing.

In this case the default stage still existed.

To make it easier to understand and have full control over what happens, first deactivate the stage you would like to remove, then delete it.